# Run .bat file from Mobaxterm

Tags: batch-file

When I am trying to run .bat file from mobaxterm on windows, it opens a default cmd window and closes it when the process is finished. Instead I want it to run from mobaxterm and log the info into a file . I searched the documentation but no luck finding the info. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "session loging" as default or just for certain sessions:

[image]